# Hadoop: Initialize mapper tasks with delay

Tags: hadoop, delay, mapper

is there any way to set up a delay between the initialization of the mapper tasks?

For example: I have set `mapreduce.job.running.map.limit` to `450`. Now I don't want `Hadoop` to create these 450 Processes at once. Instead there should be perhaps half a second between the start of every process.

Is there any chance to do this?

Comment: Just curious to know why do you want delay?

Comment: We have some strange issues with our oracle db at the moment. It has a limit of 2.500 connections. If I start the job with 450 Mappertasks, than the db denies every connection although it has free connections. If I start 50 mappertasks than everything works fine and there are about 100 used connections. The db is somehow overtaxed althought it was working just fine with 900 used connections adn 450 mapperstasks about a month ago.
So I was hoping slowing down the initialization of the mapper tasks could solve the problem.
Unfortunately our db admins don't have a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From possible list of all configurable parameters of [MapReduce](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml), it seems that your requirement of introducing delay between map tasks is not possible.

The other work around to solve your problem : Reducing number of map tasks.

`mapreduce.job.running.map.limit` is a directive to limit Map tasks but Hadoop framework may ignore this property.

I hope that you are aware of relation between InputSplit size & number of mappers. Number of mappers are decided based on InputSplits and not on DFS Blocks.

I have some crude ideas to reduce number of Mapper tasks to solve your problem. You have to play with some parameters.

```
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.node
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize
```

Change this value to multiple of DFS block size. If you have 450 process and want to have <= 50 Mapper tasks,  change the split min size to 10 times of DFS Block size.

If your block size is  128 MB, change the split.min.size to 1280 MB.

Let me know if this approach solves your problem.

Comment: I don't want to reduce the number of Mapper tasks. This can simply be modified by 'mapreduce.job.running.map.limit'. I want that there is a delay between the creation of the mappertasks. :)

Comment: I fear you can't do it.  Above parameter map.limit is just a directive and not an obligation

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your purpose by thinking exactly the other way round, i.e. If it's possible to run a MapReduce Job which requires the whole resources of your cluster (so it will block other Jobs until it's finished), and if you can control the execution time of its mapper tasks, then the tasks of your next job will start one by one each time a mapper task from the previous job is finished.
In other words, you start a job that you know how long its tasks will take, and then start your actual job.
This is easier because the first job can simply do a loop or sleep according to a parameter saved in the input files.

Comment: I could do this but then I would have the problem that the cluster is fully occupied by a senseless job and my other job. This is actually not a suitable solution for me because I do not want to fully occupy the cluster. There should be some capacity left for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible using Apache Hadoop currently.

You could limit number of initializations at the same time manually using Apache Curator's 
org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.InterProcessSemaphoreV2
mechanism for example

See for example how Cloudera uses this in batch-load jobs to load data to Solr  -

https://github.com/cloudera/search/blob/cdh6.2.0/search-crunch/src/main/java/org/apache/solr/crunch/MorphlineInitRateLimiter.java#L115

in that particular example they use it to limit number of ZooKeeper initializations 
that can be at the same time, to avoid bloating ZooKeeper with a storm of requests from hundreds of mappers.

In one job I use 400 mappers, but only limit number of initializations to to 30 at the same time (once the initializations are doen, mappers run fully independent).

In your example you want to limit number of requests to Oracle backend from mappers, in this example they want to limit number of requests to ZK. So it's the same problem.

Ideally it would be great if Hadoop had a way to put a random delay for mappers ramp-up for exact same reason. Filed enhancement request :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-7219